php / IDE way to identify all classes and methods that have less than x usages
I would like to identify all classes and public methods in my codebase that have less than 2 usages. I can see this in my IDE (PhpStorm within an open file):

Is there some way to get a list of this for everything?

Do you mean via PhpStorm? Or another way?

either a list directly in the IDE or some tool or script that I can run to give me a list
